# How can I take a certain characters from a cell of a different spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have a problem with my current code from Excel VBA.

I need to take only the last four digits from another spreadsheet, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

I'm currently using the `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, cOTr).Value` instruction to take values of other spreadsheets and the `LEFT(a,2)` and `RIGHT(a,2)` instructions to take only specific characters of a string data.

I just can't find a way to combine those two instructions.

E.g. I want to copy only the first 4 numbers of Cells from the second column from sheet 2, which has the numbers similar to 6657-2 in it, to sheet 1.

Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Edit: Lets's say I want to make a comparison between a table from spreadsheet 1 and a table from spreadsheet 2: the first table has values with four digits (e.g. 3333) and the second has values with 4 digits, a hyphen and another digit (e.g. 2222-3). I need to make a comparison between table 1 and 2, which are from different spreadsheets and to do that I only need the first four digits from table 2. I already have the logic for the program and it's running perfectly with some tests I did with only 4 digit numbers, I only need a way to take those first four numbers, something like using the "left(cells(1,2),2)" instruction but with cells of another spreadsheet.

Comment: **Not clear** ...........give some examples of data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks, I added an edit paragraph, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine text / strings by using the ampersand operator `&`

e.g.

```
=LEFT(A2,2) & RIGHT(A2,2)
```

Alternatively, you can also use `CONCATENATE`

e.g.

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2,2),RIGHT(A2,2),"some other string","and so on")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want the opposite, I want to copy string (e.g. 3333-3), but only the first four numbers into another spreadsheet.

Comment: well, then use `LEFT(A2,4)` you specify the number of characters you want to have with the second parameter. e.g. `LEFT("1234-56",4)` will give you "1234". If you're dealing with actual numbers rather than strings of number characters, you will have to convert your number to a string using the `STR` function. E.G `LEFT(STR(123456),4)` -> "1234"

Answer (score 0):

you can us this formula: `=LEFT(Sheet2!A1,4)`.

[image]

Sheet2 A1 is where you have data 2222-3.